# confusion with `Class instance methods` call

Tags: ruby

I was trying if I can call `Class instance methods` by the `instances of class` or not. Accordingly tried the below:

```
class Foo
    def show; p "hi" ; end
    def self.display ; p "hello" ; end
end
#=> nil

Foo.display
#"hello"
#=> "hello"

Foo.new.show
#"hi"
#=> "hi"

Foo.show
#NoMethodError: undefined method `show' for Foo:Class
#from (irb):7
#from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

But in the below call I expect the same error as ***NoMethodError: undefined method `display'***. But why is it not the case?

```
Foo.new.display
#<Foo:0x538020> #=> nil
foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x22bc438>
foo.display
#<Foo:0x22bc438> #=> nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an existing method [`display`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-display) on all objects.

```
class Bar
end

Bar.new.methods.grep(/disp/) # => [:display]
Bar.methods.grep(/disp/) # => [:display]
```

Your code just overwrites it for instances of `Foo`. Choose another name (`display1`, for example) and you'll see expected error.

Comment: let me try something different then. :)